# how to set values in a list in prolog for the sudoku game

Tags: list, prolog, sudoku

I have these code:

```
:- use_rendering(sudoku).

:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
sudoku(Rows) :-
    length(Rows, 9), maplist(same_length(Rows), Rows),
    append(Rows, Vs), Vs ins 1..9,
    maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
    transpose(Rows, Columns),
    maplist(all_distinct, Columns),
    Rows = [As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es,Fs,Gs,Hs,Is],
    blocks(As, Bs, Cs),
    blocks(Ds, Es, Fs),
    blocks(Gs, Hs, Is).

blocks([], [], []).
blocks([N1,N2,N3|Ns1], [N4,N5,N6|Ns2], [N7,N8,N9|Ns3]) :-
    all_distinct([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9]),
    blocks(Ns1, Ns2, Ns3).

problem(1, [[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
        [_,_,_,_,_,3,_,8,5],
        [_,_,1,_,2,_,_,_,_],
        [_,_,_,5,_,7,_,_,_],
        [_,_,4,_,_,_,1,_,_],
        [_,9,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
        [5,_,_,_,_,_,_,7,3],
        [_,_,2,_,1,_,_,_,_],
        [_,_,_,_,4,_,_,_,9]]).


        %problem(1, Rows), sudoku(Rows), maplist(portray_clause, Rows).
```

I want to make a new main function that recieves as input a list of triads, in the form [[3,7,2], [5,1,9] ...], such that
each triad corresponds to a box inside the grid that already contains a value. For example,
for the case of the previous list, [3,7,2] means that the box in row 3, column 7, contains the
value of 2, and [5,1,9] indicates that the box in row 5, column 1, contains the value of 9

This is for my personal learning, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a predicate like this:

```
board_value([R,C,V], Board) :-
    nth1(R, Board, Row),
    nth1(C, Row, V).
```

Using it like this:

```
?- Board = [[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
            [_,_,_,_,_,3,_,8,5],
            [_,_,1,_,2,_,_,_,_],
            [_,_,_,5,_,7,_,_,_],
            [_,_,4,_,_,_,1,_,_],
            [_,9,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
            [5,_,_,_,_,_,_,7,3],
            [_,_,2,_,1,_,_,_,_],
            [_,_,_,_,4,_,_,_,9]], 
   board_value([5,2,1], Board), 
   write(Board).

[[_6,_8,_10,_12,_14,_16,_18,_20,_22],
 [_24,_26,_28,_30,_32,3,_34,8,5],
 [_36,_38,1,_40,2,_42,_44,_46,_48],
 [_50,_52,_54,5,_56,7,_58,_60,_62],
 [_64,1,4,_68,_70,_72,1,_74,_76],
 [_78,9,_80,_82,_84,_86,_88,_90,_92],
 [5,_94,_96,_98,_100,_102,_104,7,3],
 [_106,_108,2,_110,1,_112,_114,_116,_118],
 [_120,_122,_124,_126,4,_128,_130,_132,9]]
Board = [[_6, _8, _10, _12, _14, _16, _18, _20|...], [_24, _26, _28, _30, _32, 3, _34|...], [_36, _38, 1, _40, 2, _42|...], [_50, _52, _54, 5, _56|...], [_64, 1, 4, _68|...], [_78, 9, _80|...], [5, _94|...], [_106|...], [...|...]].
```

It may not be obvious, but the 5th row's 2nd column is now 1. Hope this helps!